# #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
pedidos.id,
pedidos.correlativo,
pedidos.tipo_trat,
pedidos.nombres,
pedidos.apellidos,
pedidos.estado,
pedidos.token,
etapas.estado_etapa,
etapas.etapa,
hijos.opcion,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM etapas WHERE folio = pedidos.correlativo)
AS num_etapas

FROM pedidos
INNER JOIN etapas ON (pedidos.correlativo = etapas.folio)
INNER JOIN hijos ON hijos.id = pedidos.tratamiento

WHERE pedidos.tipo_trat = 2 and pedidos.cliente = '$id_us' and pedidos.correlativo = etapas.folio and pedidos.estado = 'S' GROUP BY etapas.folio
```

donde $id_us es el id del usuario que se toma del SESSION.

al generar esta consulta, me da el error:

## 1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mhenriqu_redmolar.pedidos.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

He tratado de diferentes formas y soluciones posibles, pero no he logrado solucionar el problema y no quiero deshabilitar el ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ya que lei por ahi que no es la solucion al problema.
Alguien me podria ayudar con este error o como poder solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Cuando agregas un Count(), necesitas agregar un Group by, y en ese group by debes de agrupar todos los otros campos que listaste ademas de ese count, en este caso solo estas poniendo GROUP BY etapas.folio, te faltan todos los demas. pedidos.id,
pedidos.correlativo,
pedidos.tipo_trat,
pedidos.nombres,
pedidos.apellidos,
pedidos.estado,
pedidos.token,
etapas.estado_etapa,
etapas.etapa,
hijos.opcion

Comment: Con un count no es necesario usar el group by, el problema me parece viene con el DINSTINCT, pon tu estructura de las tablas y algunos registros que tengas en cada una de ellas.

Comment: @Ricardo excelente estimado, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda y orientacion. tenia una version mas antigua de mysql en mi laptop y ahora que estoy trabajando en el vps, tengo varias consultas con el mismo problema. de verdad muchas gracias por tu ayuda. saludos

Comment: ¿como lo solucionaste al final?

Comment: @Alex agrupe (group by) todos los campos que liste en el SELECT.